# Как распарсить html элемент и получить конкретный, если все элементы имеют одинаковые атрибуты?

Tags: php, phpquery

Понадобилось распарсить интернет-магазин и получить артикул товара, цену и бренд. С первыми двумя пунктами вопросов не возникло, но бренд скрывается вот в таком куске кода:

```
  <div class="def-list__group">
        <dt class="def-list__term">Вес, кг</dt>
        <dd class="def-list__definition">
            1.076

        </dd>
    </div><div class="def-list__group">
        <dt class="def-list__term">Тип головки</dt>
        <dd class="def-list__definition">
            Phillips (PH)

        </dd>
    </div><div class="def-list__group">
        <dt class="def-list__term">Цвет</dt>
        <dd class="def-list__definition">
            Серебро

        </dd>
    </div><div class="def-list__group">
        <dt class="def-list__term">Форма головки</dt>
        <dd class="def-list__definition">
            Труба

        </dd>
    </div><div class="def-list__group">
        <dt class="def-list__term">Количество в наборе</dt>
        <dd class="def-list__definition">
            1000

        </dd>
    </div><div class="def-list__group">
        <dt class="def-list__term">Марка</dt>
        <dd class="def-list__definition">
            STANDERS

        </dd>
    </div><div class="def-list__group">
        <dt class="def-list__term">Наименование товара</dt>
        <dd class="def-list__definition">
            Шуруп

        </dd>
    </div><div class="def-list__group">
        <dt class="def-list__term">Гарантия (лет)</dt>
        <dd class="def-list__definition">
            2

        </dd>
    </div><div class="def-list__group">
        <dt class="def-list__term">Основной материал</dt>
        <dd class="def-list__definition">
            Черная сталь

        </dd>
    </div><div class="def-list__group">
        <dt class="def-list__term">Поверхность применения</dt>
        <dd class="def-list__definition">
            Гипсокартон

        </dd>
    </div><div class="def-list__group">
        <dt class="def-list__term">Тип упаковки</dt>
        <dd class="def-list__definition">
            Ведро

        </dd>
    </div><div class="def-list__group">
        <dt class="def-list__term">Тип продукта</dt>
        <dd class="def-list__definition">
            Комплект винтов

        </dd>
    </div>
```

Как получить название марки? Я использую для парсинга phpQuery.
К данному этапу дошёл вот таким путём:

```
   foreach($doc->find('dl.def-list') as $data){

     $data = pq($data);

     foreach ($data->find('.def-list__group') as $list) {

       $list = pq($list);

       echo $list;

      }

    }
```

Comment: Ну теперь найдите в `$list` `.def-list__term`, проверьте что там написано "Марка" и возьмите марку из `.def-list__definition`

Comment: проблема в том, что я понимаю это, но мне не хватает знаний это реализовать))

Comment: А говорили - не хватает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я в итоге разобрался) нужно было сделать:

```
if($list->find('.def-list__term')->text() == "Марка"){
    $brand = $list->find('.def-list__definition')->text();
}
```